# Django: get() returned more than one items -- it returned 3

Tags: python, django

I got an error

```
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one items -- it returned 3!.
```

I want edit and update an existing record in the database. Below are my model, views and html code.

Model.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Purchases(models.Model):
    bottle = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bottle_purchased = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bottle_total= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    transportation_cost = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    total_cost = models.CharField(max_length=20)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Purchases'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.bottle
```

Views function for editing.
Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Purchases
from .forms import PurchasesForm


def purchases(request):
    purchases = Purchases.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'purchases': purchases}
    return render(request, 'ht/purchases.html', context)

def edit_purchase(request):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Purchases)
    purchase = entry.purchase

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry
        form = PurchasesForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = PurchasesForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('geo_gas:purchases'))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'purchases': purchases, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'geo_gas/edit_purchase.html', context)
```

edit_purchase.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'geo_gas:edit_purchase' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <button name="Submit">save changes</button>
    </form>
```

Attached is the returned error.

```
get() returned more than one items -- it returned 3!
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyWGu.jpg)

Comment: The problem is in your `entry = get_object_or_404(Purchases)`. You have to specify the primary key to get only 1 record.

Comment: Please add your url pattern for `edit_purchase`.

Comment: url pattern ' path('edit_purchase/', views.edit_purchase, name='edit_purchase'),'

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code.  In the django error log page, you can switch to a copy-pastable view.  Use that, or the console output, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go through the django documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

it internally calls get()
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get

it will raise MultipleObjectsReturned if more than one object was found.

you need to either pass primary_key or any other fild to get_object_or_404 like:get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)

or you can use filter() if you want multiple records.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, you need to filter the queryset in `get_object_or_404` so that it only returns a single object. However the next question is how do you know which object to fetch?

The usual approach for edit pages is to include the primary key or a unique slug in the url pattern:

```
path('edit_purchase/<int:pk>/', views.edit_purchase, name='edit_purchase'),
```

You then need to update the view to accept the new argument, and use it in `get_object_or_404`.

```
def edit_purchase(request, pk):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Purchases, pk=pk)
```

Finally, you need to include the argument when you reverse the URL, e.g.

```
{% url 'geo_gas:edit_purchase' entry.pk %}
```

Comment: implemented as indicated above. It failed. But was able to resolve it in another way.

Comment: I can't spot any issuewith the above code. "It failed" isn't enough info for me to see what the problem is.

Comment: I get a type error after updating the the purchase view function.
             entry = get_object_or_404(Purchases, pk=pk)

response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: edit_purchases() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem, since the question and answer don’t use `edit_purchases` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide arguments to `get_object_or_404` not just model.

Take a look at source code of [`get_object_or_404`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L74-L95):

> ```
> def get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Uses get() to return an object, or raises a Http404 exception if the object
>     does not exist.
>
>     klass may be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet object. All other passed
>     arguments and keyword arguments are used in the get() query.
>
>     Note: Like with get(), an MultipleObjectsReturned will be raised if more than one
>     object is found.
>     """
> ```

Also consider naming your `Purchases` model as `Purchase` to follow single naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

fixed purchase function for editing - correction

```
def edit_purchase(request):

        ""Edit an existing purchase record."""
        entry = get_object_or_404(Purchases, pk=1)
        #entry = Purchases.objects.filter(pk='date_added')
        #purchase = entry.purchase

        if request.method != 'POST':
            # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry
            form = PurchasesForm(instance=entry)
        else:
            # POST data submitted; process data.
            form = PurchasesForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('geo_gas:purchases'))

        context = {'entry': entry, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'geo_gas/edit_purchase.html', context)
```